# Is it okay to configure Parse User with public "get" class-level permission?

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I'm in the process of designing my data model for an iOS application where I'm using Parse for the backend (first time using Parse)

Every user of my application has **both private data** that should be readable and writable only by the owner of the data and **public data** which should be readable by everyone.

I'm considering keeping my **publicly readable data stored in Parse's built in User object** and the private data in another custom object. Is there any downside to this? My app uses Facebook Login exclusively and, thus, when a user is created the authData field is populated with "Facebook: 12345..." **Is having this accessible to everyone a security problem?**

In this scenario the User object (my public data) would need "Get" not "find" permissions, I just need it to be readable by anyone who knows the objectId. So that rules out anyone just dumping my entire User's table.

I've read through the documentation and the "sensitivity" of each user's authData wasn't clear. **I realize that if I were using a traditional username/password scheme it would be a problem, but is it for Facebook login?** Any help/tips are appreciated.

EDIT:
I printed an entire user object to the console on a test client (with another, different user logged in) and authData wasn't returned. Am I right to assume that my suggested strategy wouldn't be a problem then? authData appears to be a "special" field that isn't returned if another user fetches it.

Comment: How about doing it the other way around, and keeping the private data within the User table itself, and making another table with all your publicly writeable fields there? letting everyone write on the user doesn't sound too cool.

Comment: Right now, only the owner of the user can write to it, but it is publicly "get-able" with an objectId. I did start off using your suggestion but due to how my app works it, it would be less efficient. I have many objects that simply house relationships between users (an array of user pointers in some object). Having another object (non user object) represent the user would be burdensome. Especially when I need to query for it in my cloud code functions to confirm that this other object does indeed belong to the requesting user.

Comment: If you're not letting anyone write on the user then you're fine. Parse users are by default publicly readable by all, but only writeable for that user itself.